# «Сто и более» или «сто или более»?

Tags: грамматика

Дорогие коллеги, при переводе англоязычного интерфейса StackOverflow на русский возникло следующее разногласие среди переводчиков.

Какой из вариантов перевода соответствует литературной норме?

- «Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более баллов»
- «Ответ с рейтингом 100 или более баллов»

Розенталь, кажется, рассматривает лишь формы с «и». Но всё же хотелось бы получить квалифицированный совет.

---

Уточнение: речь идёт об *одном* ответе, набравшем *n* баллов, где *n* ⩾ 100.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если речь идёт об *одном* ответ**е**, то "100 **или** более", поскольку свойственное конкретно ему количество баллов не может оказаться одновременно равным числу 100 и большим его.

Вариант "100 **и** более" может относиться только к *множественному* числу и разным ответам, среди которых могут одновременно найтись ответы с количеством баллов 100 и ответы с бОльшим числом баллов. Во втором случае (ответ**ы**) допустимы *оба* варианта: в варианте с *или* "ответы с рейтингом 100 **или** более баллов" будут трактоваться как "*каждый из ответов*" с указанным (для единичного ответа) рейтингом.

**P.S.** Пример формального текста (из Уголовного кодекса): "убийств**о** двух **или** более лиц" во *всех* случаях упоминания в тексте (а их более 10) употреблено с "или" - очевидно, по изложенной выше причине (невозможно "убить двух **и** более").
http://www.allpravo.ru/library/doc101p/instrum3433/item3446.html

Comment: Ну, текст УК вполне может отходить от литературной нормы. «Не _наказывается_, а _наказуется_, не _поступок_, а _деяние_...»

Comment: В каком законе вы встретили глагол "наказуется" и почему считаете слово "деяние" выходом за пределы литературных норм?

Comment: Это [из классики](http://petrov.com.ua/GoldCalf/pages/06.htm) же! А слово «деяние» вне круга литературоведов вызывает такое же впечатление древности, как и «паки-паки-иже херувимы». Так просто не говорят.

Comment: Пример из статьи закона я привёл потому, что такие тексты проходят лингвистическую экспертизу, в частности, на соответствие нормам современного литературного языка. Но здесь достаточно и простой логики. Поставлен вопрос и ожидается ответ. Рейтинг этого ответа может оказаться меньшим 100, равным 100 и большим 100 баллов. Если рейтинг будет меньше 100, ответ (например) не будет принят, если рейтинг этого ответа окажется 100 или более баллов, ответ будет принят. Принят он будет в одном из двух несовпадающих случаев: значение рейтинга или 100, или больше.

Comment: Ожидать логичности от понятной людям фразы я бы не стал, язык по сути нелогичен. Например, общепринятое сокращение «более-менее» (или, ещё хуже, «более-не-менее») в общем-то нонсенс, в отличие от оригинала «более или менее». В любом случае есть trade-off между понятностью и точностью. Но мне кажется, наше обсуждение уходит в офтопик. В любом случае, я понял вашу точку зрения, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Литературной норме соответствуют оба, но значительно чаще используется вариант с "и". Причем не важно, единственное это число или множественное. Не стоит дословно переводить с математического на русский знак "больше или равно".

Answer (score 3):

### Ответ Граммы.ру

> С точки зрения норм лексики и грамматики русского языка оба варианта являются правильными.

Фраза "100 и более баллов" задает диапазон рейтинга и подразумевает те толкования, о которых пишут участники дискуссии: 1) ответ имеет рейтинг 100 баллов, 2) ответ имеет рейтинг более 100 баллов. В тексте, отражающем идею "может быть и то, и то", эта фраза уместна.
Фраза "100 или более баллов" задает альтернативу (или 100, или более 100), которая в каких-то ситуациях может быть важна, существенна и т. п. Допускаем, что в случае с ответом эта альтернатива тоже имеется, но нам о ней ничего неизвестно.
Резюме: противопоставлять два варианта при условии, что они выражают идею 'ответ имеет рейтинг в диапазоне 100 и более баллов', оснований нет.

Comment: "Ничего не известно" пишется раздельно!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой: Не предерайтесь к правопесанию!

Comment: не известно (отрицается "известность") - неизвестно (утверждается "неизвестность").

Comment: Все логично и правильно! Ошибок нет!

Comment: Утверждается неизвестность ничего? Утверждать можно неизвестность чего-то, а не ничего. Посмотрите ответ Грамоты: http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=32021 (над цифрой 2). Она, по-Вашему, неправа?

Comment: в знач. сказуемого отсутствуют сведения, знания ◆ Мне ничего об этом неизвестно. См. Викисловарь. То же написано в словарях на Грамоте.ру.

Comment: А насчёт этого ответа (Грамоты) всё-таки что Вы скажете? Вот ещё пример с ничего (конец 1-го пункта): http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_556

Comment: Викисловарь не авторитетный источник, а подтверждения того, что Грамота то же пишет, Вы не даёте. А я Вам показываю обратные примеры.

Comment: Я же сказала: посмотрите в словарях Грамоты.ру. К тому это ответ Граммы.ру.

Comment: Я посмотрел и привёл Вам обратные примеры, а Вы не привели никаких, просто голословно утверждаете, будто там такое есть.

Comment: Что Вы смотрели? Там же написано: Неизвестно: в знач. сказ.

Comment: Смотрел на Грамоте. А про мои два примера Вы что скажете? Они как раз с Грамоты.

Comment: Для того, чтобы рассуждать о "диапазоне" рейтингов, нужно эту условность выразить отдельными словами - без этого "рейтинг ответа" указывает не на попадание в диапазон, а на принимаемое значение, которое может оказаться тем или иным. Ссылка на частоту употребления - тоже слабый аргумент: во многих сложных случаях ошибается большинство говорящих. Успехов Св. Грамме :) .