# "Ничего не( )известно"

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Вчера я предложил правку в [ответе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419288/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5/419472#comment419660_419472) Натальи из gramma.ru. Я исправил фразу "но нам о ней ничего неизвестно", написав "не известно" раздельно, но Наталья не приняла моей правки. И спор разгорелся в комментариях, где Наталья ссылалась на статью в Викисловаре, где действительно так написано, но, на мой взгляд, это не очень авторитетный источник. Она также ссылалась на Грамоту и говорила, что на ней предлагают писать слитно такое, при этом никаких примеров не привела, а я ей привёл обратные примеры (из той же Грамоты). Всю эту дискуссию можно увидеть в комментариях по той же ссылке.

Кто же прав?

Comment: Артем,если опираться на правило  - раздельно.  Но в Национальном корпусе очень много примеров слитного написания. Здесь надо учитывать и другой момент. В правилах говорится, что некоторые наречия,в т.ч. и наречие "не/известно" пишутся то раздельно, то слитно, без особой смысловой разницы.

Comment: Много примеров там слитного написания именно с "ничего"?

Comment: Да,Артем. Можете убедиться сами.

Comment: И правда. :((((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Нацкорпусе встречается около 25% слитных написаний "ничего неизвестно", поэтому нельзя однозначно считать их неграмотными.

Согласно формальному правилу, мы имеем усиление отрицания "ничего не известно", и лучше в формальных текстах придерживаться этого правила во избежание лишних вопросов.

Но вот усиление отрицание здесь чисто формальное, "ненастоящее", так как местоимение "ничего" имеет предметный характер и не является наречием степени.

Сравните:

(1) Мне **это** нужно. - Мне **ничего** не нужно. Это формальное отрицание, такова структура отрицательного предложения при наличии местоимения.

(2) Мне это **очень** нужно. - Мне это **нисколько** не нужно. Это отрицание, которое усиливается отрицательным наречием.

Аналогичная ситуация с "ничего не известно", где пользователи или пользуются формальным правилом, или не считают нужным этого делать, не чувствуя усилительного значения местоимения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Вера!

Comment: Непонятно только, в чём разница между "ничего не нужно" и "ничего не известно".

Comment: Я задаю вопрос: неизвестно что? Ничего. Очень странно получается. На мой взгляд неизвестно может быть что-то, а не то, что отрицается.

Comment: "Не нужно" пишется всегда раздельно, а (не)  известно имеет две формы написания, поэтому "ничего не нужно" пишут раздельно все, а "ничего не известно" могут написать и слитно, если не будут придерживаться формального правила. Я здесь на стороне формального написания, потому что слишком детальный анализ  мало что дает в семантическом отношении, но при этом значительно усложняет правописание.

Comment: Радует, что Вы тоже на стороне раздельного написания в данном случае! :)

Answer (score 3):

В "ничего" видим НИ. Как известно, это усилительная частица, и усиливает она отрицание. Значит, отрицание должно быть. Пишем раздельно.

Это я так, "базу подвёл", на письме в подобных случаях пишется просто автоматом. Естественно, раздельно.